# SQL Query not having a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows:

```
------+-------------+------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------+
| id   | customer_id | date       | action_type_id | details                                        |
+------+-------------+------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------+
| 4225 |         324 | 2015-09-07 |              1 | Sent mail Malcolm Murrey                       |
| 6320 |         324 | 2017-05-08 |              3 | quotes for price.                              |
|  156 |         326 | 2013-07-25 |              3 | Site visit to price job                        |
|  943 |         326 | 2013-10-23 |              1 | Arranged visit for snags on panel              |
| 1135 |         326 | 2013-11-28 |              1 | Arranged visit for site mod                    |
| 1930 |         326 | 2014-04-15 |              2 | Quoted for new HMI                             |
| 2644 |         326 | 2014-10-20 |              2 | Sent email about pending quote for HMI         |
| 2821 |         326 | 2014-11-25 |              1 | Screen problem                                 |
| 2184 |         328 | 2014-07-21 |              1 | Sent email detailing services                  |
+------+-------------+------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to find the `customer_id` of customers that don't have an `action_type_id` of 2. In this case 324 and 328 but just can't seem to figure it out.

I was thinking I could do something like `group by customer_id not having action_type_id = 2`.... any help much appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE action_type_id <> 2 GROUP BY action_type_id, customer_id`?

Comment: You need a self join

Comment: @jx12345 your question says 326, but I see action_type_id=2 entry in the sample data, please edit and correct the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use aggregation:

```
select customerid
from t
group by customerid
having sum(action_type_id = 2) = 0;
```

I find the use of `group by` and `having` for this type of query to be very flexible on the conditions you might have (say you want 2 and 3, or not 2 but either 3 or 4).

Comment: I like that - it's a bit more readable for me - do you think it will be more expensive than the self join over a large dataset?

Comment: @jx12345 . . . It depends.  If you use `select distinct`, you are doing a `group by` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by a left join to itself on records with an id of 2, then filtering on those without a match.

Something along the lines of

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id 
FROM customer a
LEFT JOIN customer b
ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
AND b.action_type_id = 2
WHERE b.customer_id IS NULL
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT a.customer_id` to resolve ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `not exist`:

```
select * 
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table 
                  where customer_id  = t.customer_id and 
                        action_type_id = 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this,

```
select distinct customer_id from customer where  action_type_id <> 2
```

Comment: Because this returns all customer_ids - they all have an instance of action_type_id <> 2 -  I want to find the ones that never have action_type_id == 2 which is different to returning individual records that are action_type_id <>2

Comment: ohh I got it now check this once, select distinct customer_id from customer where  action_type_id <> 2 and customer_id not in (select customer_id from customer where action_type_id =2 )

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT customer_id FROM customers WHERE action_type_id <> 2
```

Comment: I don't think this works because the table has several entries for each customer_id where this is true. What I want is the a list of customer_id that never have action_type_id == 2